# restrict object so it can't go off the window

Tags: pascal

```
program CircleMoving;
uses SwinGame, sgTypes;

procedure Main();
var 
    x, y, CIRCLE_RADIUS: Single; screenColour: Color;
begin
    OpenGraphicsWindow('Character Moving', 800, 600); 
    Delay(5000);
    x := 400;
    y := 300;
    CIRCLE_RADIUS := 150;
    screenColour := ColorWhite;

    repeat
        clearScreen(screenColour);
        fillCircle(ColorGreen, x, y, CIRCLE_RADIUS); 

        RefreshScreen(60); 
        Processevents();

        if KeyDown(LeftKey) and (x - CIRCLE_RADIUS < ScreenWidth()) then
        begin
            x := x - 1;
        end;

        if KeyDown(RightKey) and (x + CIRCLE_RADIUS < ScreenWidth()) then
        begin
            x := x + 1;
        end;

        if KeyDown(UpKey) and (y - CIRCLE_RADIUS < ScreenHeight()) then
        begin
            y := y - 1;
        end;

        if KeyDown(DownKey) and (y + CIRCLE_RADIUS < ScreenHeight()) then
        begin
            y := y + 1;
        end;

until WindowCloseRequested();
end;

begin
    Main();
end.
```

At the moment when I run the code it works other then when I move the circle to the left and up it goes off the window, I do not want this to happen. I want it to be restricted so the circle will stop and wont go any further once it hits the edge. I want it to be the same on all side so when I move the circle in any direction it will stop at the edge of the window. Moving the circle to the right and down works but left and up does not. I believe the problem is at the if statements starting at line 22. How do I change my code to fix this?

Comment: When moving left or up you are checking against width and height. You should check against the leftmost (and upmost) positions, which are ... (I'm sure you know).

Comment: I'll give you a hint. What is the value of x when the circle is at the left of the window? Do you see why the if statement with the KeyDown(LeftKey) will be true and the x:= x - 1; will execute? That if statement needs to be false when the circle is at the left of the window so that the value of x is not decremented.